# Android: Why do we need to use R2 instead of R with butterknife?

Tags: android, butterknife

I've been using [butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) for a few months and I've just noticed in its documentation that it says:

> Now make sure you use R2 instead of R inside all Butter Knife
>   annotations.

Why is that? I've been using R and everything works perfect.

Comment: I found that the ids value in R2 for any res (color, dimen, ...)  is the same as in R. only the difference in R2 is the annotation like "@DrawableRes" and "@IdRes", and used this annotation to be sure you return correct and the expected type. for example "@ColorRes" return value is expected to be a color resource reference, and "@DrawableRes" return value is expected to be a drawable resource reference.

Comment: @Sally So you're saying that if I use R2 I will get compile time errors in case I try to bind an id to a wrong type?

Comment: I excepted that, annotations help us to improve code inspection https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using R2 is only necessary for building Android Library projects.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#library-projects

It has to do with fact that the values in the R.java generated class aren't  declared as "final" when built as part of a library. The annotations used for @BindView() need these R. values to be final and not subject to change later on.

I'm sure someone could explain all of this better -- but the bottom line is - you're just fine using "R." values in @BindView in an Android application

Comment: Okay I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: For a bit further explanation, I have an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577106/final-field-in-r2-java-in-butterknife/