# Android: Gradle compilation error expects element value to be a constant expression - Feature Module

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack, android-instant-apps

This is my first multi-module project.

This login activity exists in a Feature Module which gets many of its dependencies from a Base Feature Module.

I'm getting the error `error: element value must be a constant expression` on lines where I'm using `@BindView` with my TextInputEditText and Button.

Also, I noticed that the import for the `R` class is missing, yet none of the `R.id.` are in red. Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Feature modules are similar to library modules. Once you move from an application module to a library/feature module, your `R` class fields aren't final constants anymore. That's why the issue happens. To fix this,  you will need to switch to Butterknife's `R2` class.

More info in the links below:

- Official documentation: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#library-projects
- [Android: Why do we need to use R2 instead of R with butterknife?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362062/android-why-do-we-need-to-use-r2-instead-of-r-with-butterknife)
- https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1113 <- This mentions you may need ButterKnife 9.0